# How to replace characters in string

Tags: string, replace

How do I replace ";" with "," in string "Red; Green; Blue"?

```
{% set rgb = "Red; Green; Blue" %}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Twig has a [replace filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) for that. You can replace strings/vars with strings/vars:

```
{% set string = "I love apples" %}
{% set var = "like" %}
{% set string = string|replace({'apples': 'kiwis', 'love': var}) %}

{{ string }} {# Prints "I like kiwis" #}
```

Your example:

```
{% set rgb = "Red; Green; Blue" %}
{% set rgb = rgb|replace({';': ','}) %}

{{ rgb }} {# Prints "Red, Green, Blue" #}
```

Comment: Worth noting that Craft actually comes with its own version of the replace filter, which actually supports a simpler syntax if you’re only replacing one thing: `|replace('apples', 'kiwis')`

Comment: Thanks for this! Helped me out with replacing something with a variable.